# We currently use GCM with an api key but I see no quota or current usage data in web GUI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I know google rolled out the new FCM as well but I am poking around trying to find out from google's website how much we are currently using for sending notifications through GCM.  I can't seem to find any information on this or charts in the web GUI.

When I click on the project(the one with the api key we currently use and does currently work), I then click on 'dashboard'.  There is a chart that says 'There is no traffic for this time period'.  At the same time, we are sending around 100k notifications per second and have been for years.

It also says on the dashboard page "Enabled APIs - Some APIs are enabled automatically"

Below the charts there is a table with the column 'API' and these two listed

Google Play Android Developer API
Google Play Game Services Publishing API

Neither one has any data.

My ultimate goal is to create a 'new project' and a 'new api key' so that I can add our team's members to that project to wall it off.  My issue is I don't see how to create the old GCM api at all.  It's as if I can only swap out the key and that is it.

EDIT: ouch, it gets worse.  The api key we generate doesn't work(after waiting about 5 minutes after creation) while I see the old api key right there and that is what we are using so that is really confusing.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: From [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500427/how-to-enable-reports-for-gcm-in-google-developer-console), It is possible that if you are using GCM and not FCM the stats will not be working.  Apparently, GCM did not have a quota limit but instead [rate limits](https://plus.google.com/+GoogleDevelopers/posts/a9d5NvPz2di)

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? If so please post answer it will benefit the rest of the community.